# Catching OverflowError

Tags: python, python-3.x, overflowexception

In Python 3 I have a class representing a range [x,y] of values and computing the length of such range.

If the length is too large, I'm not sure how to catch the OverflowError exception **inside** the class itself. It is raised only in the outer code using a class instance...

```
class ValRange:
    val_min = None
    val_max = None
    range_len = 0

    def __init__(self, val_min, val_max):
        self.val_min = val_min
        self.val_max = val_max

    def __len__(self):
        if (self.val_min is not None and
             self.val_max is not None):
            length = 0
            try:
                length = int(self.val_max) - int(self.val_min) + 1
            except OverflowError as e:
                # Somehow no exception is caught here...
                print('OverflowError...')
                length = 10**5  # arbitrarily large number
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            if length > 0:
                self.range_len = length
        return self.range_len


import traceback
import uuid
x = uuid.UUID('00000000-cb9d-4a99-994d-53a499f260b3')
y = uuid.UUID('ea205f99-0564-4aa0-84c3-1b99fcd679fd')
r = ValRange(x, y)
try:
    print(len(r))
except:
    # The exception is caught in this outer code and not in the class itself. Why?
    print(traceback.format_exc())

# The following, which is equivalent to the operations in the 
# code above, will work. 
a = int(y) - int(x) + 1
print(a)
```

This is what happens upon execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rira/bugs/overflow.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(len(r))
OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

311207443402617699746040548788952897867
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `OverflowError` doesn't occur within your magic `__len__()` method - Python is perfectly capable of handling much bigger integers than that - but in CPython `len()` itself is implemented as [`PyObject_Size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Size) which returns a [`Py_ssize_t`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/#specification), which is limited to `2^31-1` (32-bit) or `2^63-1` (64-bit) and thus the overflow occurs when your `__len__()` result is *coerced* to it.

You can do a pre-check before returning the result to make sure you capture the overflow before it even occurs, something like:

```
def __len__(self):
    if (self.val_min is not None and self.val_max is not None):
        length = int(self.val_max) - int(self.val_min) + 1
        if length > sys.maxsize:
            print('OverflowError...')
            length = 10**5  # arbitrarily large number
        self.range_len = length
    return self.range_len
```

Comment: Oh I see. So `len(r)` raises the error, while `r.__len__()` won't.

Comment: @RickyRobinson - Pretty much. Blame it on the way built-ins are implemented. If you really find it too annoying, you can always override the `len()` built-in to check if the target object has `__len__()` and call that, otherwise revert to the built-in `len()`.